# Pattern Recognition problem : $... ,224,8,3,4,11,...$

Tags: logical-deduction, pattern

> The following pattern was given to me by one of my friend:
>   $$\color{red}{224}$$
>   $$14 \quad \quad 8$$
>   $$4 \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad 3$$
>   $$8 \quad  \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad 4$$
>   $$7 \quad  \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad 11$$
>   $$\color{blue}{Z \quad20}$$
>   $$\color{red}{Y \quad \quad  \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad 44}$$
>   $$\color{blue}{10 \quad 30}$$
>   $$5 \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad 2$$
>   $$9 \quad  \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad 17$$
>   $$7 \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad 8$$
>   $$5 \quad \quad 8$$
>   $$\color{red}{80}$$
>   $\color{red}{Y} \quad \& \quad \color{blue}{Z} =?$

**My Thoughts:**
For the $\color{blue}{\text{blue}}$ colored terms :
We find:
$$(11 \times 4 )- (3 \times 8)= \color{blue}{20}$$
$$(8 \times 8 )- (17 \times 2)= \color{blue}{30}$$
$$(5 \times 9 )- (7 \times 5)= \color{blue}{10}$$
$$(14 \times 4 )- (8 \times 7)= \color{blue}{0=Z}$$

> $\implies \color{blue}{Z=0}$

But I am not able to recognize the  $\color{red}{\text{red}}$ colored terms,so any help please...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe

> $ Y = \boxed{70} $

because

> each number at the ends of the diamond is equal to two times the product of the adjacent numbers. $$ \begin{gather*} \color{red}{224} = 2 \times 14 \times 8 \\ \color{red}{44} = 2 \times 11 \times 2 \\ \color{red}{80} = 2 \times 8 \times 5 \\ \color{red}Y = 2 \times 5 \times 7 = \boxed{70} \end{gather*} $$